# discrete numpy array to continuous array

Tags: numpy, interpolation, array-broadcasting

I have some discrete data in an array, such that:

```
arr = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[2,2,2],[1,1,1]])
```

whose plot looks like:

[image]

I also have an index array, such that each unique value in arr is associated with a unique index value, like:

```
ind = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4],[5,5,5]])
```

What is the most pythonic way of converting arr from discrete values to continuous values, so that the array would look like this when plotted?:

[image: Data here is made up for visual purposes only]

therefore, interpolating between the discrete points to make continuous data

Comment: Have you tried some smoothing, e.g. mean filter?

Comment: yes I did try something along those lines but smoothing and interpolating was causing a shift in the data

Comment: regarding the shift, why should your left point (0, 1) have a higher weight and stay, but your right point (14, 1) changes to about (14, 1.5). Could you mathematically describe the constraints to better understand what exactly you are looking for? I would have expected a symmetric and therefore shifted outcome...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this if anyone has a similar issue. It is maybe not the most elegant so modifications are welcome:

```
def ref_linear_interp(x, y):

    arr = []

    ux=np.unique(x) #unique x values
    for u in ux:
        idx = y[x==u]
        try:
            min = y[x==u-1][0]
            max = y[x==u][0]
        except:
            min = y[x==u][0]
            max = y[x==u][0]
        
        try:
            min = y[x==u][0]
            max = y[x==u+1][0]
        except:
            min = y[x==u][0]
            max = y[x==u][0]
    
        if min==max:
            sub = np.full((len(idx)), min)
            arr.append(sub)
        else:
            sub = np.linspace(min, max, len(idx))
            arr.append(sub)

    return np.concatenate(arr, axis=None).ravel()

y = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[2,2,2],[1,1,1]])
x = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4],[5,5,5]])
z = np.arange(1, 16, 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer for the symmetric solution that I would expect when reading the question:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create the data as described
numbers = [1,2,3,2,1]
nblock = 3

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": np.arange(nblock*len(numbers)),
    "y": np.repeat(numbers, nblock),
    "label": np.repeat(np.arange(len(numbers)), nblock)
})
```

Expecting a constant block size of 3, we could use a rolling window:

```py
df['y-smooth'] = df['y'].rolling(nblock, center=True).mean()

# fill NaNs
df['y-smooth'].bfill(inplace=True)
df['y-smooth'].ffill(inplace=True)

plt.plot(df['x'], df['y-smooth'], marker='*')
```

If the block size is allowed to vary, we could determine the block centers and interpolate piecewise.

```py
centers = df[['x', 'y', 'label']].groupby('label').mean()

df['y-interp'] = np.interp(df['x'], centers['x'], centers['y'])
plt.plot(df['x'], df['y-interp'], marker='*')
```

Note: You may also try
`centers = df[['x', 'y', 'label']].groupby('label').min()` to select the left corner of the labelled blocks.